# Passin Bit field parameters to stored procedure using Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, parameterized-query

All,

I've been stuck on the following issue all day. I'm trying to make a parametrized stored procedure call that includes three bit field parameters. The exception I keep encountering is **"Error converting data type nvarchar to bit."**

Here is my source code:

**Stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_TestParamProc
    @price_segment_set_id VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
    @segment_group_id VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
    @segment_price_band_id VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
    @segment_id VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
    @include_source_price_bands BIT = 0,
    @apply_segmentation BIT = 0,
    @print_sql BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM MarketingSegmentDetails
    WHERE SegmentID = @segment_id

END
GO
```

---

**C# code:**

```
        var segment_id = "1";
        string segment_group_id = "1";
        string segment_price_band_id = "1";
        string price_segment_set_id = "1";
        var include_source_price_bands = false;
        var apply_segmentation = false;
        var print_sql = false;

        using (var context = new PricingContext())
        {
            var list = new List<object>();
            list.Add(price_segment_set_id == null
                         ? new SqlParameter("price_segment_set_id", DBNull.Value)
                         : new SqlParameter("price_segment_set_id", price_segment_set_id));
            list.Add(segment_group_id == null
                        ? new SqlParameter("segment_group_id", DBNull.Value)
                        : new SqlParameter("segment_group_id", segment_group_id));
            list.Add(segment_price_band_id == null
                        ? new SqlParameter("segment_price_band_id", DBNull.Value)
                        : new SqlParameter("segment_price_band_id", segment_price_band_id));
            list.Add(segment_id == null
                        ? new SqlParameter("segment_id", DBNull.Value)
                        : new SqlParameter("segment_Id", segment_id));
            list.Add(include_source_price_bands == null 
                        ? new SqlParameter("include_source_price_bands", DBNull.Value)
                        : new SqlParameter("include_source_price_bands", Convert.ToBoolean(include_source_price_bands)));
            list.Add(apply_segmentation == null
                        ? new SqlParameter("apply_segmentation", DBNull.Value)
                        : new SqlParameter("apply_segmentation", Convert.ToBoolean(apply_segmentation)));
            list.Add(print_sql == null
                         ? new SqlParameter("print_sql", DBNull.Value)
                         : new SqlParameter("print_sql", Convert.ToBoolean(print_sql)));

            var segments = context.Database.SqlQuery<usp_SegmentProcessing>("usp_TestParamProc price_segment_set_id, segment_group_id, segment_price_band_id, segment_id, include_source_price_bands, apply_segmentation, print_sql", list.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm falling behind in project work.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Why are you declaring your boolean parameters as vars?  Try declaring them as bool, then remove your convert.toboolean statements.

Comment: force of habit declaring implicit types. I will try your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try doing something like

```
list.Add(
   new SqlParameter("print_sql", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit) { Value = (print_sql != null ? print_sql : DBNull.Value) }
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z.aspx

Comment: I figured out my issue. It was two part. One was declaring the SqlParameter as SqlDbType.Bit. The second part is the stored procedure has a cursor declared in it which was causing a problem as well. Thanks for the help.